# BigQuery REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, google-bigquery

I have a query that is defined as;

```
var query = " SELECT " +
            "REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(destination_value), r'[^\d]+', '') " +
            "FROM table1";
console.log(query,'query');
bigquery.query(query, function(err, rows) {
            if (err === null) {
                return resolve(rows);
            }else{
                return reject(err);
            }
            });
```

When I print the query it's returning

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(destination_value), r'[d]+', '') FROM `table1`;
```

Why the special characters from my query is not there when I console it? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double escape the backslash in the regex metacharacter `\d`, because the first backslash will be consumed by JavaScript.  Try the following:

```
var query = "SELECT " +
            "REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(destination_value), r'[\^\\d]+', '') " +
            "FROM table1";
```

I would not expect that `^` would also need to be escaped, but I have done so since it seems this character is also causing a problem.  You can verify in the demo below that the query prints correctly.

### Demo